# Microsoft Graph API: "Access Denied" moving a DriveItem when using a personal accounts

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

For work accounts, [moving an item by updating its ParentReference](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_move) works fine.

Personal accounts throw an "Access Denied" error. 
Is this a limitation of the API, a problem in the API, or an issue in the .NET SDK?

Example code:

```
driveItem.ParentReference = new ItemReference() { Id = newParentFolderDriveItem.Id };

var folder = graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderId]
            .Request().UpdateAsync(driveItem).Result;
```

Comment: This should work, but the code you've included isn't complete enough to know what might be going wrong. Are you trying to move the item into another folder in the same drive, or to a different drive? Does your app have read-write access (OneDrive.ReadWrite)?

Comment: The move is in the same drive, and the app has OneDrive.ReadWrite. Delete, Upload, etc. works fine (therefore permissions are fine). Regarding the code, the same code (now edited here to add some clarity) works fine for business accounts.